# How to check If both select and input field is selected and filled up using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a html form where a `select` field and `input` box exist and I am using 2 class for that which is `work_phone_class` and `work_phone_class_input`.

I am calling ajax by `trigger` a save button with a class when `select` field value is changed or any option selected **AND** again calling ajax when user complete typing on `input` box. So that I am using following jQuery code :

```
$(".work_phone_class").change(function() {            
    $(".save_phone_class").trigger('click');
});

$(".work_phone_class_input").change(function() {            
    $(".save_phone_class").trigger('click');
});
```

Now I want to `trigger` the save button with the class **when `select` field value is selected AND user completed typing on `input` box.**

**Update :**

Html form is look like this. I think I have to use `$(this)` but not sure.

```
<select class="work_phone_class">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1"></option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="work_phone_class_input">
<select class="work_phone_class">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1"></option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="work_phone_class_input">
<select class="work_phone_class">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1"></option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="work_phone_class_input">
```

Comment: have you set a maximum character length in your input box? maybe use that to trigger the save button?

Comment: @NirbhayTandon, now it's trigger the save button by individually. BUT i want to trigger the save button when both select and input field is selected and filled up.

Comment: you can add the Boolean flag to check whether user has made the proper entry in the form field and then do the required action.

Comment: one of the answers below should have helped. you just need to properly use &&

Comment: @NirbhayTandon Yes but both are negative mark :(

Comment: dont down vote something if it doesnt work for you, just write a comment and let the person know.

Comment: Don't look at vote, try to test if it work for you, it's a good answer. If not, explain why you can't use this

Comment: @shibbirahmed check my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no so clear about your requirement.... but i think this will help you

```
$(".work_phone_class,.work_phone_class_input").change(function() {     

$(".work_phone_class_input").each(function(){ 
if($(this).val() == ""){
//// Validation goes here for input
return false;
}
})
$(".work_phone_class").each(function(){ 
if($(this).val() == undefined){
//// Validation goes here for input
return false;
}

//// trigger your save button click here
    })



    });
```

please let me know if it helps by marking it as an answer

Comment: not working. It's calling trigger the save button when I select the select field. Its should be trigger the save button when both select and input box is selected and filled up.

Comment: Please try to check the conditions. Or for the concern update your question with full HTML code

Comment: Can you create a JsBin for the same illustration?

Comment: aah there you are..... Please make sure you are explaining your question correctly. @Alexis already updated with right answer to your question.you can use the same code. thank you

Comment: My full html and jQuery code a bit longer. should I post all here ?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add a test before send your ajax..

**UPDATE**

```
$(".save_phone_class").click(function(){
  var allFilled = true;
  $(".work_phone_class").each(function(){
      if($(this).val()=="")
         allFilled =false;
   });
  $(".work_phone_class_input").each(function(){
      if($(this).val()=="")
         allFilled =false;
   });
  if(allFilled)
  {
      //AJAX
  }
});
```

```js
$(".work_phone_class_save").click(function(){
  var allFilled=true;
  $(".work_phone_class_input").each(function(){
    if($(this).val()=="")
      allFilled=false;
  });
   $(".work_phone_class").each(function(){
    if($(this).val()=="")
      allFilled=false;
  });
  if(allFilled)
  {
    alert("Ajax sent");
  }
  else
    alert("All input are not filled");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="work_phone_class">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="work_phone_class_input">
<select class="work_phone_class">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="work_phone_class_input">
<select class="work_phone_class">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="work_phone_class_input">
<button class="work_phone_class_save">Save</button>
```

Comment: I want to trigger the save button when both select field is selected and input box is filled up. No need to press the save button by manually

Comment: Well, Now I got the idea. Your code helped me a lot. Thanks @Alexis :)

Comment: you can trigger this function at any change in your form, the form will be send only if all input are filled